# Wordpress - displaying archive and single posts on different custom post type

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I am relatively new to developing with Wordpress, I’m a designer first, developer second.

I am creating a directory website. I have a members login area where users create a post under the post type, “my-business”. They then access their post for editing from the front-end once logged-in at; domain.com/my-business/xyz

I have the above working.

Now where I am stumped is, I want to display an archive and the posts  data mentioned above under a different post type “business” for non logged-in users at a url like this; domain.com/business (as archive) and domain.com/business/xyz as the post.

I’m not sure if I’m going about this the wrong way, any tips or advice would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

If I use a WP query loop calling the custom post type “my-business” in the archive-business.php file the title and all permalinks want to go to the original post under “my-business” instead on “business”

Answer (score 0):

Keeping everything that you have working so far, the way I would do this is:

1. Create a new post type: business.
2. Use the wp_insert_post hook: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post/ to detect when a post of type "my-business" is created/updated.  When this happens, check to see if a post of type "business" exists with this same slug, and if not, create it.
3. If needed, open and update each of your my-business posts so that a business post is created for each, or write a script to loop through them all and take care of this.
4. To handle the business archive page, use the pre_get_posts hook: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/  Inside the callback, test to see if a business archive page is being accessed, and if it is, switch to the my-business post-type (  $query->set( 'post_type', 'my-business' );   )  This code will go in functions.php, or a plugin. This will make it so that when someone visits the /business page, they see a list of the posts of type my-business.
5. In archive-business.php, instead of outputting the permalinks (which would now be links to the /my-business/xyz), get_the_permalink and replace 'my-business' with 'business' - now all the links on this page will go to '/business/xyz'.
6. In single-business.php inside the loop, collect the slug of the post and use it to query for the post of post_type my-business that has the same slug - this will give you access to all the values the business owner has set for the business and you can display them here however you like.